# Is there a way to Store a Query in View/Procedures?

Tags: database-administration, sqldeveloper

I wrote an Oracle query and I run it manually from SQL Plus or SQL Developer.

It has 2 parameters; start and end date/time.

Is there a way to store this query in a view or procedures and run it from there?

Comment: I feel you would get a better response on [dba.se].

Comment: You can create a procedure with the parameters that you require to be used in your query, if you create a view you'll need to provide the columns in your query in order to be used in the where clause, from my point of view it would be better the proc approach.